# After upgrade to 18.04: extended text selection in Unity lost

Tags: unity, touchpad, multi-touch

In Ubuntu 16.04 (using Unity), I have been able to perform the following action:

1. I was able to mark parts of a text with pressing and moving one finger on the touch-pad.
2. Quite often, I haven't been able to select more text, as the end of the touch-pad was reached.
3. In this situation, I kept pressing this finger and started to move another finger on the touch-pad. This second touch enlarged the selection area of the text.

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 and switching the default window manager back to Unity, this second touch (#3 above) does not have any effect anymore.

Nevertheless, I am able to use the two-finger scroll.

**What do I have to do to perform action #3 as in Ubuntu 16.04?**

========================================

**EDIT:**

**TLDR;:** Installing, executing, uninstalling [touchpad-indicator](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/04/install-touchpad-indicator-ubuntu-18-04-lts/), and rebooting helped.

**My remaing question is: how can I understand what was changed implicitly?**

Long story:

Somehow I managed to solve my problem by myself.

Already some days ago I added the `ppa:atareao/atareao` and installed the `wheather-indicator`.

As I did not get any clue for my touch-pad problem, I installed the  [touchpad-indicator](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/04/install-touchpad-indicator-ubuntu-18-04-lts/) (which is also part of that ppa) just to see whether some of its options would improve my situation.

After installing and executing it, I could not find any option that helped. In parallel, I got asked via the `Software Updater` windows dialogue to update some system libraries. After doing this, I uninstalled `touch-indicator` again and performed a reboot, as the `Software Updater` dialogue requested this.

After the reboot it is working again.